# Track Active Item in NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

NERDTree has `:NERDTreeFind` to find the current file in the tree.

How can I make NERDTree update the current file in tree automatically whenever I switch files?

Comment: By asking for that feature on nerdtree's issue tracker.

Comment: I asked just now, thank you. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it, but be aware that the frequent updates make switching buffers quite slow:

```
:autocmd BufEnter * if &filetype !=# 'nerdtree' | NERDTreeFind | wincmd p | endif
```

The conditional avoids triggering a find if the NERDTree sidebar itself is entered.